# Kivy Accordion layout inside a Carousel

Tags: python, kivy

New to Kivy, but absolutely loving it. I've been toying with some of the different layouts and I'm trying to put an accordion on the second page of a carousel. The first page of the carousel is just a label and it works fine.

The problem is when I slide to the second page the accordion is not lined up like it should be. It's very zoomed in and the labels are off to the side. I can't even see all the items in it. I've attached a picture of the outcome.

Here is my code...

```
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel

class Example1(App):

    def build(self):
        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')
        upcoming = Label(text="This is a boring label")
        carousel.add_widget(upcoming)

        self.testDictionary = {"Test1": "Hello World", "Test2": "This is a test", "Test3": "To See how this formats"}
        root = Accordion(anim_duration=1.5, orientation='vertical')
        for verseLoc, verse in self.testDictionary.iteritems():
            item = AccordionItem(title=verseLoc)
            item.add_widget(Label(text=verse, text_size=(200, None)))
            carousel.add_widget(item)

        return carousel

Example1().run()
```

[image: How it should look]
^How it looks by itself^
[image: A picture of how the accordion ends up looking]
^how it looks inside a carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `AccordionItem`s directly to the `carousel`. You need to add `item`s to `root` and outside the `for` loop add `root` to the `carousel`.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Stupid mistake on my part.